# Change text size for all TextView without affecting text size in ListView

Tags: android

I made the default text size of all TextView smaller (12sp):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/smallTextSize</item>  
</style>

<style name="smallTextSize">    
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>    
</style>
```

However, the text inside all ListView also becomes smaller. Why is that, and what can I do to avoid this (I don't want the text inside my ListView to be affected)?

Answer (score 0):

ListView contains from items that can contain TextView.
So if you changed style for all TextViews you changed it for ListView item's TextView.

To change text size in ListView:
You can create XML layout for ListView item and set other style to TextView with desired text size.

Or you can change text size programmatically in ListView adapter applying setTextSize(...) to TextView(s).